# Magento - Can't change customer address in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, address

I have Magento 1.8.1 CE and cannot change the customer address anymore. I do not know what has changed, I have not done this for a while.

When I go to the customer screen in admin I get this error on the main page.

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
>   `this.itemContentTemplate = new Template('#{company}`

Then I go to the addresses
Then I get this error:

> ReferenceError: `customerAddresses` is not defined

I cannot change an existing address either.

Changing on the front-end is possible, and successful But the customer also gets a warning that it isn't saved?

There are no entries in the `system.log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have modified the `Address Templates` and you put an invalid character in there. Go to `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates` and restore `JavaScript Template` to its default value:

`#{prefix} #{firstname} #{middlename} #{lastname} #{suffix}<br/>#{company}<br/>#   {street0}<br/>#{street1}<br/>#{street2}<br/>#{street3}<br/>#{city}, #{region}, #{postcode}<br/>#{country_id}<br/>T: #{telephone}<br/>F: #{fax}<br/>VAT: #{vat_id}`

Then check if that fixes your issue.

Comment: If you don't mind, click on the "Tick" to mark it as resolved :)

Comment: I will do that ... but i can't do that yet ....
I have to wait 5 min ....